# Looking for a obj-c equivalent of this openSSL command

Tags: objective-c, encryption, openssl, key, salt

I am looking for obj-c code that is equivalent to this command

openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k secret -P -md sha1

Once you type the above in command you get this output

salt=538C5F5ECAB7BFA2

key=43EB4C7D68263389D069381E48B6E0F3

iv =E26E4B49D75FA7C0CD82C40BB761B50A

Answer (score 2):

Any code I've seen using openssl from objective-c has used `NSTask` to run the openssl command.

Something like this should work (I've used something similar without any problems):

```
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"enc", @"-aes-128-cbc", @"-k", @"secret", @"-P", @"-md", @"sha1", nil];

NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/openssl"];
[task setArguments:args];
[task launch];    // Run
[task waitUntilExit]; // Wait
```

Then your response should be in `[task standardOutput]`.